# How to convert web application from Java Server Faces to HTML5?

Tags: html, jsf

I Want to covert my web application from JSF to HTML5 web application. While doing conversion i am getting the problem with value binding I do not know how to do the value binding for HTML5 components.

I have searched a lot but I did not get any useful solution. If anybody knows please help me thank you.

Comment: Do not ask a too broad question. Ask about the **specific** problem you're currently struggling with.

Comment: i want to do the value binding using html5 components like jsf

Comment: You can do so, but that requires JSF(+Facelets), which thus totally contradicts your initial question. You would still end up with a JSF web application.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two things together. You cannot simply "convert" JSF app to HTML5, but you probably can adapt your JSF app, so it will produce HTML5 (or at least HTML5-like) output.

HTML5 is a front-end (browser) technology, whereas JSF is back-end (server) technology. There is virtually nothing in the (pure) HTML5 that could bind the front-end components with the back-end data - well, unless you use Javascript and AJAX. If you aim to make your web application a so called Single Page Application, I would recommend you to look at Javascript frameworks, such as [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), or maybe - for the start - [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: you can make an SPA with JSF to ;-)

Comment: I haven't written you can't ;-) But do the JSF implementations contain enough support for it, or have you to make the browser part separately anyway (and thus use some JS framework)?

Comment: Both can be done. With the html5 friendly markup, you can combine jsf with a javascript framework (never tried it though, since I do not see the need for myself) and have the javascript part act as the view part for complex ui components but still have ther advantage of server side validation/xss checks/csrf and populating the model. Not sure how easily this would work though. And with JSF component sets like PrimeFaces you can create SPA's but not something like a fully self contained page that does not need ajax or whatever.